# how to install lxde in centos 7

Tags: linux, x11, centos7

I installed a 64bit  Centos7 in my virtualbox running in windows7. The default desktop of the centos is genome3. I don't like it. So I am trying to install lxde desktop in my CentOS7. I searched the internet and tried lots of methods and I am still not having any luck. The command from lxde wiki doesn’t work at all

```
# yum install lxde
```

I got "No package lxde available."

I found on the web some said to use rosalab.repo
http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2013-April/134465.html , it's still not working. It seemed the repo was broken.
Can anyone give me some instructions on how to install lxde on Centos7? Thank you in advance.

Comment: apparently you either have to compile it from source on Centos since LXDE apparently is not in any official centos repo or epel. more info here :http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Installation. if you still want something out of the box, try Fedora spin with LXDE from here: http://spins.fedoraproject.org/